# Spring Boot Thymeleaf variables blocking login page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, variables, authentication, thymeleaf

I'm making a webshop in Spring Boot 2.1.1, with ThymeLeaf 3.0.11
My login page does not appear in every cases, everytime it wants to load it gives a "TemplateInputException" and fails to show up.
I figured it out, if I delete thymeleaf variables from the body or div tags (I mean th:with attributes), then it works until it reaches the next html tag with TL variables, after that, the html page just stops to render. What could be the problem? There is no scenario  where i dont use those variables, I need them in the container tag. What is the relation between the Spring Boot login page and template variables?
I copy some code, if you need any more, please let me know.
Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my Webconfig:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){

    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("auth/login");

    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

}
```

My security config's configure method:

```
@Override
public void configure (HttpSecurity httpSec)throws Exception {
    httpSec
        .authorizeRequests()

        .antMatchers("/", "/reg", "/login", "/css/**","/images/**",  
        "/js/**", "/register", "/error", 
        "/records", "/search", "/record", "/altercart", 
        "/showcart", "/category", "/viewchange",
        "/images").permitAll()

        .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")

        .anyRequest().authenticated()

       .and()

        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll() 
       .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .permitAll();

}
```

My login page(using layout dialect):

```
<div layout:fragment="content">
  <div>

            <div th:if="${param.error}" th:text="#{login.error.wrongusernameorpassword}" class="col-12 error-message"/>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}" th:text="#{logoutSuccess}" class="col-12 success-message"/>
            <p th:text="#{logingreetings}" class="col-12"/>
            <form method="post" th:action="@{login}">
                <input type="text" name="username" th:placeholder="#{login.ph.username}" required class="col-12"/>
                <br />
                <input type="password" name="password" th:placeholder="#{login.ph.password}" required class="col-12"/>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" th:value="#{loginSubmitButton}" class="col-12"/>
                <br /><br />
            </form>
            <br />

            <a class="col-12 anchor" th:href="@{register}" th:text="#{misc.registration}">Registration</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Beggining of stack trace:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during 
template parsing (template: "class path resource 
[templates/auth/login.html]"
```

Comment: If you look at more than just the beginning of the stack trace, it will tell you what the error is.

Comment: You were right. I thought the stack trace errors with my variables are just the consequences of the main problem, but it is true vica versa. I removed the vievcontroller from my Webconfig.java. It does not inject modelattributes to the view, so I just have to left this work to my main controller class, where all modelattributes are added automatically. Now it works!  Thank you!